# Minimise code repetition by creating a reusable template

Tags: python, django

I have a template which includes 4 different paginators that only differ in context variables (tasks_today, tasks_tomorrow, ... etc.), and I want to minimise code repetition so I don't have 4 different paginator templates.

Template:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Today</h3>
    <table>
    {% if tasks_today %}
        {% for task in tasks_today %}
            {% include 'todo/task_table_row.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% include 'todo/paginator_today.html' %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No tasks for today.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    <h3>Tomorrow</h3>
    <table>
    {% if tasks_tomorrow %}
        {% for task in tasks_tomorrow %}
            {% include 'todo/task_table_row.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% include 'todo/paginator_tomorrow.html' %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No tasks for tomorrow.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    <h3>Upcoming</h3>
    <table>
    {% if tasks_upcoming %}
        {% for task in tasks_upcoming %}
            {% include 'todo/task_table_row.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% include 'todo/paginator_upcoming.html' %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No upcoming tasks.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    <h3>Past</h3>
    <table>
    {% if tasks_past %}
        {% for task in tasks_past %}
            {% include 'todo/task_table_row.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% include 'todo/paginator_past.html' %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No tasks in the past.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </table>
</div>
```

`paginator_today`:

```
{% load url_replace %}

{% if tasks_today %}
<div class='paginator'>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if tasks_today.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_today=1 %}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">begin</span>
            </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

    {% for n in tasks_today.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if tasks_today.number == n %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <span class="page-link">{{ n }}
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        {% elif n > tasks_today.number|add:'-3' and n < tasks_today.number|add:'3' %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_today=n %}">{{ n }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if tasks_today.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_today=tasks_today.paginator.num_pages %}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">end</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

`paginator_tomorrow`:

```
{% load url_replace %}

{% if tasks_tomorrow %}
<div class='paginator'>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if tasks_tomorrow.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_tomorrow=1 %}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">begin</span>
            </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

    {% for n in tasks_tomorrow.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if tasks_tomorrow.number == n %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <span class="page-link">{{ n }}
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        {% elif n > tasks_tomorrow.number|add:'-3' and n < tasks_tomorrow.number|add:'3' %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_tomorrow=n %}">{{ n }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if tasks_tomorrow.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page_tomorrow=tasks_tomorrow.paginator.num_pages %}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">end</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

What can I do?

`url_replace.py`:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django import template
​
register = template.Library()
​
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.dict()
    query.update(kwargs)
    return urlencode(query)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What's the difference between the paginator templates?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the difference is context variable `tasks_today`, which can be `tasks_tomorrow`, `tasks_upcoming` or `tasks_past`, and `page_today` which can be `page_tomorrow`, `page_upcoming` or `page_past`. I've included another template so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `with` keyword to set certain variables inside your include template:

```
{% include 'todo/paginator.html' with tasks=tasks_today page='page_today' %}
```

You can then replace references to `tasks_today` in you paginator template to `tasks`, as well as the reference to `page_today` to `page`

---

Edit: The call to `url_replace` is problematic, since it uses kwargs, and a call like `{% url_replace page_today = x %}`, will be equivalent to a call to `urlreplace(context, **{'page_today' : x})`.

Simply calling url_replace with `page = x` will not work correctly, since it will pass a keyword argument with the name of `page` instead of the value of `page`

The naive solution would be to pass a `page` variable to the `paginator.html` and call `{% urlreplace **{page : 20} %}`, but the Django template engine does not allow packing kwargs.

I think the best way to go here is to create a `url_replace_single` function, since in this use case you only replaces one value. 
To do this, you'll need to define a field and value parameter on you url_replace function:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, field, value, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.dict()
    query_dict = { field : value}
    query.update(query_dict)
    return urlencode(query)
```

Then call the function from your template like this:

```
{% url_replace field=page value=x %}
```

The only downside is that this will only let you replace one query parameter in your url.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, however it doesn't work as expected, the URL looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/?page=2`, instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/?page_today=2`.

Comment: Where does `url_replace` come from? Do you have the source for that?